# change save dialog's default path in Electron, javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

With the source code of "https://jsfiddle.net/soulwire/4ooupev9/"

```
function encode( s ) {
    var out = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ ) {
        out[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Uint8Array( out );
}

var button = document.getElementById( 'button' );
button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {

    var data = encode( JSON.stringify({
        name: 'Example object',
        child: {
            name: 'Nested thing'
        }
    }, null, 4) );

    var blob = new Blob( [ data ], {
        type: 'application/octet-stream'
    });

    url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    var link = document.createElement( 'a' );
    link.setAttribute( 'href', url );
    link.setAttribute( 'download', 'example.json' );

    var event = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
    event.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    link.dispatchEvent( event );
});
```

I was able to implement the json-save code.

But **the problem is I need to change the default download path to my project folder.**

Is it possible to do so?

I'm going to use this in Electron App.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Since you're using Electron you can use [`dialog`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog), where default path is just a parameter.

Comment: @pergy Thank you so much for your sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#Save").click(() => {
    dialog.showSaveDialog({
        title: "Save Data", 
        defaultPath: "C:\Users\username", // Default Path 
        filters: [{ name: 'Data File', extensions: ['json'] }],
    },
        (jsonFileName) => { // callback function
            // Save Here
        });
});
$("#Load_HITS").click(() => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog(
        {
            title: "Choose a HITS Data File to load",
            defaultPath: HITSDataPath,
            filters: [{ name: 'HITS Data File', extensions: ['json'] }],
            properties: ['openFile']
        },
        (jsonFileName) => {
            // load file
        }
    )
});
```

With the help of pergy's comment, I was able to find how to use and here is my code.